# Tag Wiki Excerpts not showing when viewing newest questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

No tag wiki excerpts at all are being presented to users viewing the newest questions using those tags. For instance, the excerpt from [syntax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) reads

> Questions on correct (or improved) formulation of Mathematica code to achieve particular results. Use this tag (not "symbol") for questions about all those odd @@ /@ # and ~ characters.

Yet, the users are presented with

> Useful links Overview tutorial on Mathematica syntax A list of (almost) all Mathematica syntax Mathematica syntax with non ASCII characters Some of the more common syntax and special operators Apply (@@ and @@@) Map (/@) and MapAll (//@) Prefix (@) Infix (~) Postfix (//) ReplaceAll (/.) and ...

which is the first several lines of the full tag-wiki entry. This same problem exists on every other tag I've examined.  The lack of mark up in the summary panel often makes these unreadable.

Comment: We are still deciding what to do here, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120946/the-excerpts-at-the-top-of-tag-question-lists-have-been-replaced-by-the-first-f for full context.

Comment: @SamSaffron thanks for the info, I searched, but did not find that question.

Comment: suggestions of how to deal with this, more than welcome ... the issue I have with excerpts are that they are not inviting. this may be a non-problem now that we have an info tab. I am going to let the current changes back for a bit, then may switch it back and see if it has a negative effect

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] per [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120946). Closing it as TL so that the damned bot doesn't bump it up in the future...